# ZINNIA_MEDIA_URL is not defined or not recognize on django

Tags: django, django-settings, zinnia

Hi I've been trying to play around with zinnia, nevertheless the CSS is not well applied because it cannot find (or it's in blank) a setting variable called ZINNIA_MEDIA_URL

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ ZINNIA_MEDIA_URL }}img/favicon.ico" />
```

I tried to setted my self, but without any luck. Has anyone encouter this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The variables in the settings module doesn't get added as context-variables automatically do they? The view have to do it, which you do in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look and I cannot find any reference to ZINNIA_MEDIA_URL in the current version of zinnia.

I *did* find a note in the readme that zinnia uses Django's 1.3 staticfiles app to handle its css/javascript media now. Look at https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/master/zinnia/templates/zinnia/skeleton.html and you'll see  "{{ STATIC_URL }}" in there.

So perhaps you took the ZINNIA_MEDIA_URL from an older example or older version of the docs? Or you upgraded to a newer zinnia version?

Comment: I downloaded a version using pip let me check if that the problem thanks

Comment: indeed on 0.9 version skeleton.html used ZINNIA_MEDIA_URL currently is using STATIC_FILES download the new version and added everything worked fine thanks!